# How to calibrate xbox 360 controller?

Tags: controllers, windows-10

I've got a new controller and it works wrong, so i tried to calibrate it and after 4 hours it still doesn't work properly.

Issue: sticks have no dead-zone, and X and Y axis on right stick cant go    separately.)

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault with the controller. Return it?

Comment: Bare in mind, it's uncalibrated

Comment: Windows 10 wants an XBox One controller.. They actually make it very difficult to get a 360 controller to work with it. You will have to do a bit of work to get them working.. it will -not- work right out of the box.

Comment: Ah, missed the Windows 10 tag.

Comment: @maksloboda - please don't add the answer to the question body :)

Comment: @Studoku - maks has confirmed that it was a hardware fault, would you like to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is a hardware problem. If you can, test the controller on an Xbox 360.

If it won't work on a 360, it's broken. Return it to whomever sold it.